# angular2-infinite-scroll - argument of type number is not assignable to parameter of type string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nginfinitescroll

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll library to add infinite scroll in my Angular 2 app but I'm getting the following error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As each element of `array` has object like `{id: number}`, you should be pushing `object` with `id` property with `number` value in it inside `array`.

```
array.push({id: i})
```

Comment: it is showing me the same error if I add string inside the object. 
e.g. `array = [{ id:  1, title: 'name ' }];`

Comment: @w3debugger what is your actual object structure?

Comment: `{
    id: 1,
    userImage: 'tracymcgrady-avatar.jpg',
    userName: 'tracymcgrady',
    distance: '500m',
    postImage: 'leaf_iphone_case_hard_plastic.jpg',
    price: '230 AED',
    likesCount: 32,
    postText: 'Leaf iPhone Case Hard Plastic',
    postTags: ['iphone','case','mobile','phones','macbook'],
    commentCount: 12,
  }`